# Assigning ease in functions programatically only

Tags: c#, silverlight

For unfortunate technical reasons with the software I use, it is near impossible to add ease in functons to my user control elements.

If, for exampe, I have a UserControl (not the ones which come in a Silverlight 3 project), and I want to assign the bouncingeasein function to a specific control only via C#, how can I do this?

Thanksc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new BounceEase object and assign it to the EasingFunction property of your animation.